Why does this static_assert on a pointer to an incomplete type in a templated function apparently work?
In the process of replacing a static_assert in a templated function with a requires statement, we discovered that firstly, the function was occasionally being used on an incomplete type, and that secondly, this apparently compiled. The version with the requires statement, of course, is illegal.
Here's a simple version of the apparently-functioning static_assert:
#include <type_traits>

struct Bar {};

template<typename T>
inline Bar* AsBar(T* ptr)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<T*, Bar*>);
    return (Bar*)ptr;
}

struct Foo;

void DoThing(Foo* f)
{
    AsBar(f);
}

struct Foo : public Bar {};

This surprises me! My model of how the templating works is that at the point of instantiation, all the code is generated, and at that point we invoked std::is_convertible_v on an incomplete type, which is undefined behaviour. Sticking a non-templated version of the same function at that point fails.
So I have some questions:
Firstly, does the templated static_assert that is working for an incomplete type have defined behaviour? Or are we simply 'getting lucky' with undefined behaviour?
Secondly, if it's defined, why? What is incomplete about my understanding of templates?

This has nothing to do with templates. If you want to cast to a pointer then C++ happily lets you do so, no complete type is needed (the size of the pointer is known at compile time and that is enough). Side notest : do NOT use "C" style casts in modern C++ code e.g. (Bar*) should be reinterpret_cast<Bar*>. Also do not use static_assert like this, use SFINAE or concepts to remove function templates as candidates. auto* AsBar(T* prt) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T*,Bar*>,Bar*> . Summary : since you have two pointers they can always be converted.

A pointer type is always a complete type. For example, say we have struct Foo; then Foo* is complete while Foo is not.

I suspect this example either exhibits undefined behavior, or is ill-formed no diagnostic required (I always forget which). AsBar<Foo*> has two points of instantiation (one right after DoThing, and the other at the end of the translation unit) that give it different meaning. Your compiler probably just happens to pick the latter point of instantiation (if I recall correctly, GCC always chooses that).

@user12002570 Haha thanks for that summary :)

@IgorTandetnik The point of instantiation is also at the end of translation unit. See Can the point of instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?

@PepijnKramer You're welcome.

@user12002570 [temp.point]/7 "If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule (6.3), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required." The problem is not that there are two points of instantiation, but that the meaning of the function depends on which one is picked.

@IgorTandetnik Yes, and as explained in the link I gave all three compilers pick the later version and [temp.point]/7 is not violated.

@user12002570 The fact that three implementations agree on the choice doesn't make the program well-formed according to the standard.

@IgorTandetnik But here [temp.point]/7 is not violated as there is no violation of one definition rule.

@user12002570 I can't find chapter and verse at the moment, but that can't be true. Surely if I define something like inline std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_convertible_v<Foo*,Bar*>> f() in two translation units, where in one Foo and Bar are incomplete and in the other they are complete and Foo derives from Bar, that must be an ODR violation - in effect I'm declaring std::true_type f() in one place and std::false_type f() in the other.

@IgorTandetnik I am particularly talking about the given question. You can always make a program IFNDR if you try hard enough and allowed to edit the question/files in c++.

@user12002570 I am too. I'm saying that it can't be true that std::is_convertible_v<Foo*, Bar*>  has the same meaning under ODR whether or not Foo is a complete type (because if it were true, that would lead to absurd outcomes, one of which I've shown; it's a reductio ad absurdum logical argument). And therefore [temp.point]/7 does apply and the code in the given question is ill-formed NDR.

@IgorTandetnik Using inline  would complicate this issue further. And since it is not used in the given example and inline has other meaning(it is used to prevent multiple definition error) as well and in your comment a working demo would be nice and taking the intention of this change in the standard(that made point of instantiation at end of TU), I think we could probably create a new separate question which will use your given example with a [mcve]. So that these two questions don't get mixed up. You can ofourse give a link to this one.

@IgorTandetnik Also, if you find exactly how this example violates ODR I would update my answer. But as I said, it doesn't violate it afaik.

@user12002570 The section on ODR never mentions the word "meaning", so it's not immediately obvious exactly what "different meanings according to the one-definition rule" refers to. However, ODR does specify the circumstances under which two class definitions or two inline function definitions don't violate ODR: such definitions must consist of the same sequence of tokens, and there's a long list of further conditions (e.g. that all names should resolve to the same entities in both places); in other words, those tokens must have the same meaning. (continued)

@user12002570 The only reasonable approach I can see then is to conclude that "two points of instantiations have different meaning under ODR" should be read as "if these two points of instantiation were two definitions of the same function, they would have violated ODR". It would be difficult to argue that two definitions of a function, where one in effect contains static_assert(false) and the other static_assert(true), don't violate ODR.

tldr; The end of a translation unit is considered a point of instantiation, at which point Foo is complete. Additionally, a pointer type is a complete-type.


Firstly, is the templated static_assert working for an incomplete type defined behavior?

A pointer type is a complete-type because the size of the pointer object does not depend on the size of the pointed-to type

The following types are incomplete types:

the type void (possibly cv-qualified);
incompletely-defined object types:

class type that has been declared (e.g. by forward declaration) but not defined;
array of unknown bound;
array of elements of incomplete type;
enumeration type from the point of declaration until its underlying type is determined.




Note none of the bullet points are satisfied/applicable for the pointer type in your example.


Perhaps I’m missing something, but why doesn’t the static assert fail here? I agree the pointer type is a complete type, but it shouldn’t be convertible to Bar*

Additionally, the point of instantiation of a function template is also at the end of a translation unit where Foo is complete. Can the point of instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?

A c-tagged question Why are pointers to incomplete types allowed and not variables of incomplete types?

Perhaps I’m missing something, but why doesn’t the static assert fail here? I agree the pointer type is a complete type, but it shouldn’t be convertible to Bar*.

@templatetypedef Because the point of instantiation of the function template is also at the end of the translation unit where Foo becomes/is complete. See Can the point of instantiation be delayed until the end of the translation unit?

Even if the types are not convertible, pointers can always be converted (even if the result is UB when you try to use that converted pointer). Maybe what you intend to do is more like checking : std::is_convbertible_v<T,Bar> (e.g. can the non-pointer types be converted)

@PepijnKramer std::is_convbertible_v<Foo*, Bar*> does produce false for two complete unrelated types Foo and Bar. You seem to be saying that it would return true for any pair of pointers - that is not the case.

Thank you! "templates are instantiated at the end of the TU" is the detail I was missing that explains this.

@IgorTandetnik No that was not what I was trying to say. If OP wants the pointer conversion to fail between unrelated types he must check the types not the pointer types.

@PepijnKramer Why "must"? std::is_convbertible_v<Foo*, Bar*> does too fail for unrelated types.

@IgorTandetnik Ok, I missed that... I assumed it would succeed. Apologies for the confusion

To be clear in the actual code we do not have a C-style cast between two types; it's just an example. The ability to write Foo* f = some_bar is what we're checking for.
